# Make VS code read webpack.config and recognize path with alias?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm working with Webpack and Visual Studio Code and in order to avoid things like:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../services/authentication/service';
```

I've created aliases on my webpack.config so I can use:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from 'services/authentication/service';
```

However, by doing so Visual Code is not able to detected my code and therefore I lose the intelisense for my classes.

Does anyone have a solution for that, is there a way to make VS code to read the webpack.config and recognize the path with the alias?

thanks in advance

Comment: I do have VSCode (1.3.1) recognizing webpack's aliases in js files. Aliases do not work in typescript. Are you talking about javascript or typescript?

Comment: yes I'm using typescript.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

update typescript@2.0.0 and you can map the same webpack aliases on tsconfig.json by adding:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["src/app/*"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway of doing this with jsconfig? Paths option doesn't seem to have any affect here

Answer (score 28):

I ran into a similar issue. Because I was using javascript rather than typescript, I had to create a `jsconfig.json` file and use the `paths` option appropriately.

Assuming a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── foo.js
│   ├── jsconfig.json # your vscode js config
│   └── my-module     # folder you're aliasing
│       └── bar.js
└── webpack.config.js # your webpack config
```

This wound up working for me:

1. Set up webpack resolve alias:

   ```
   var path = require('path');
   module.exports = {
     resolve: {
       alias: {
         "my-module": path.resolve(__dirname, './src/my-module')
       }
     },
     // ... other webpack options
   };
   ```
2. Modify jsconfig.json in your src folder:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6",
       "paths": {
         "my-module": ["./my-module"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use the alias:

   ```
   // in foo.js
   import Bar from 'my-module/bar';
   Bar.quack();
   ```

Comment: how about import javascript file directly?

Comment: this worked for me. But not on all components. 60% of my files are being suggested.

Comment: This works but I had to add the path with the wildcard as `"styles/*": ["./src/components/styles/*"],` as expressed in the documentation [jsconfig.json Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases)

Comment: This worked for me, didn't even need the `webpack.config.js` just the `jsconfig.json` was enough

Answer (score 18):

Install VSCode extension [PathIntellisense](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense) .

To open your VSCode setting file, you can press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on macOS(on Windows is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), find "a pair of curly brackets button" on the top right corner, click it.

In my situation, I want to use the symbol `@` as an alias of the path `./src` . So I add this configuration to my VSCode setting file:

```
  "path-intellisense.mappings": {
    "@": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
  }
```

Use `${workspaceRoot}` when the path should be relative to the current root of the current project.

You can find the official example [here](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense#mappings) .

---

Original answer:

I use the VSCode extension [PathIntellisense](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense) .

Configure this [setting](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense#mappings) in my VSCode setting file.

Now VSCode could recognize the path with the alias.

Comment: I'm not actually sure why this was downvoted. While the OP did ask for `tsconfig` it is very possible that someone else, like me, was searching for this due to finding some bit of info pointing towards it being the only option to "teach" VSC about the aliases. Since this is specifically about VS Code it seems perfectly valid as an answer.

Comment: @Jared Likely because the answer doesn't contain any actual information; it just links to the extension, making the answer essentially nothing more than "use PathIntellisense". Including more details and an example configuration *in the answer itself* would be a good step into making this an actual answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this answer so much. Just note: by this way, it's not enough for indicate the destination path on click on imported path or exported name (should be done by `jsconfig.json`. It just helps for auto complete the path name suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

You need to specify the `paths` and `baseUrl` fields in your jsconfig.json file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./app/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

See [path mapping documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md#path-mapping)

Comment: this is magic, i searched a lot but only this works

Comment: Is there a difference between the two?
"~/*": ["./app/"]
"~/*": ["./app/*"]

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents since I needed to tune a little bit other solutions.

In our case, we defined at `webpack.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const paths = {
 src: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
}

...

   alias: {
        '@components': paths.src + '/components/',
        '@styles': paths.src + '/styles/',
        '@utils': paths.src + '/utils/',
    },
```

So we use those alias as:

```js
import { foo } from '@utils/date';
```

This `jsconfig.json` do the thing:

=> **please note the `/*` as in `@components/*`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@styles/*": [
        "styles/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where does `paths.src` come from?

Comment: @mix3d edited the response , now should be clearer

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete)
 extension for VSCode

It's better than PathIntellisense for me.

Just add Config:

```js
  {
    "javascript.suggest.paths": false, // disable default suggestion
    "path-autocomplete.extensionOnImport": true,
    "path-autocomplete.pathMappings": {
    "@": "${folder}/src" //custom what you want
  },
```

[Work screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3mu.gif)

Comment: Where do I add this config?

Comment: This worked for me. @Pixsa the settings to change are the vscode `settings.json`.
I suggest you edit those settings based on the project needs. Edit the `workspace settings` instead of user settings.

1. `ctrl + shift+ p`
2. Look for workspace settings.json
Add these lines abover