# VSCode and Webpack alias

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not using `path-intellisense`, only the built in VSCode plugins.

When using Webpacks alias feature, VScode is reporting..

`Unable to resolve path to module <Name of Alias>`

Webpack alias setup is like..

```
alias: {
      components: './client/javascripts/components/',
      .....
```

and a `jsconfig.json` is setup like...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": [
        "./client/javascripts/components/*"
      ],
```

Are there any other configs / steps necessary to fix this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044010/make-vs-code-read-webpack-config-and-recognize-path-with-alias

Answer (score 0):

It can be the problem in your file of webpack

try with this

```
 resolve:{
  alias:{ 
       components: path.resolve(__dirname,'client/javascripts/components/')
  }, 
},
```