# VS Code "Go To Definition" Not Working When Importing Without Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up VS Code to allow me to `cmd+click` or `right click + Go To Definitions` when importing JS components that are not using relative nor absolute paths. Rather these are set up by Webpack to look for any file within a folder regardless of depth.

Example of my folder structure:

```
code/
├── backend/
├── frontend/
│   └── resources/
│       ├── css/
│       └── js/
│           ├── notifications/
│           │   ├── alerts.js
│           │   └── mail.js
│           │
│           ├── sidebar/
│           │   └── panes/
│           │       └── account.js
│           │
│           └── footer/
│               └── main.js
│
└── jsconfig.json
```

Example of how I try to import a component (I'm using React) from `/code/frontend/resources/js/footer/main.js`:

```
import Mail from 'mail';
import Account from 'account';
```

Example of my current VS Code `/jsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*" : [
        "*",
        "code/frontend/resources/js/**/*"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

I basically want to tell VS Code to make the `js` directory the root directory where I can import any JS file from without using a path so that it can allow me to use the `"Go To Definition"` option. I'm sure it can be done I just dont know how. Any ideas?

**NOTE:** Just to re-iterate, I can not use paths when using `import`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Just FYI, my code runs on the browser correctly, since webpack handles the paths at run time, thats not the problem. I just cant get VS Code to learn what the path is in order to use their `"Go To Definition"` feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make VS code read webpack.config and recognize path with alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044010/make-vs-code-read-webpack-config-and-recognize-path-with-alias)

Comment: @Herohtar it is not a duplicate as they are asking specifically for paths with an Alias. I can not use any aliases for the path, just the file name (without extension) like `'mail'` in `import Mail from 'mail';`

Comment: What are you doing to get webpack to import the files if not by using alias?

Comment: @Herohtar Webpack is setup correctly, it uses a resolve option to handle that at runtime. My code runs on the browser with the correct paths, thats not the problem. I just cant get VS Code to know what the path is in order to use their `"Go To Definition"` feature.

Comment: `jsconfig.json` is what tells VS Code what paths to use. It behaves similarly to webpack aliases. I'm not sure if you can use wildcards to match all directories; `*` only matches a single portion of a path, and `**` isn't allowed.

Comment: yea i think theres something missing in my `jsconfig.json` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Below one may be helpful. Worked for me

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Check this for more options https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options